# ion-buttons with buttons (Ionic 3)

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I use ion-buttons for create one space with two buttons. I need allocate one button in right and other button in left, but don't it work, the buttons stay misaligned.

Image for better visualization of the problem:
[image: Image for better visualization of the problem]

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <!--Testes-->
        <ion-buttons>
            <button ion-button color="dark" (click)="btn_reportlog()">Reportar Log</button>
            <div class="btn_right"><button ion-button color="danger" (click)="btn_deletlog()">Excluir Log</button></div>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: in your scss add: `.btn_right{ float: right; }`

Comment: Its work. I had declarated in scss, but not using float. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `ion-buttons` tag inside a `ion-toolbar` you can position your `button` tags using properties like `start` `end` `left` `right` source: [ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/#buttons-in-a-toolbar). No need to touch CSS here, let ionic do it for you.

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons>
            <button ion-button color="dark" (click)="btn_reportlog()" start>Reportar Log</button>
            <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="btn_deletlog()" end>Excluir Log</button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```